No se ejecuta mis funciones de JavaScript en móviles
recién estoy introduciendo al mundo de programadores necesito ayuda estoy usando workpress y encontré un código de convertir los input a mayúsculas y me esta funcionando correctamente en la web de escritorio funciona correctamente pero al momento de probar en teléfonos no me funciona.
Alguna recomendación como convertir ese código para que lo reconozca he estado probando fucionarlo con touchend, tochstart y no he tenido buenos resultados
Este es el código que estoy utilizando
$(document).ready( function () {
  $("input").on("keypress", function () {
   $input=$(this);
   setTimeout(function () {
    $input.val($input.val().toUpperCase());
   },50);
  })
 })


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! workpress sera wordpress??? en fin... y probasta al cambiar el texto al perder el foco??
